# Spring Tool Suite shows errors in Controller and Service classes but builds and runs successfully

Tags: spring-boot

Because of this issue when I'm writing some new code and if there is error, I get confused if it is an actual error or is it because of this issue. So I have to build and run code again to confirm which I don't want to do again and again.

Comment: Show the error so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: Please share the errors. After that someone can help you.